# How to pass value to a public function within a class in PHP?

Tags: php, function, class, object

This is the code I have been working on, I want to pass value to a function within a class from the outside! How to do it?

```
class components {
  private $senderID;
  function __construct($sender) {
      $senderID = $sender;
  }
function hello($name) {
$jsonData = '{
"recipient":{
    "id":"'.$this->senderID.'",
    "name":"'.$name.'"
  }
}';
}
}

$component = new components($sender);
$component->hello('Rohit');
```

This doesn't seem to work! Please help!!

Comment: "Doesn't work" *how*?  Did you ever define `$username`?  What do you expect the result of this function to be?  How is this failing?

Comment: Damn, the feeling when you see your past self making such silly questions :) Anyway, thanks for the help guys!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't use `$this` in your construct to set the value of `senderID` in the scope of the object. Do it like this:

```
function __construct($sender) {
    $this->senderID = $sender;
}
```

Just change your `__construct` method to be like that and it will work.